# How to integrate Swagger into Java project using Guice + Jersey + servlet and generate REST API docs automatically

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger, guice

I have an app which uses Guice and Jersey for REST services. How do I configure Swagger in Guice? I already have the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-jersey2-jaxrs', version: '1.5.0'
```

How do I generate the API docs automatically? Someone who has faced similar issues, please shed some light on this integration. Thanks a lot!

Guice like:

```
public class ServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
 @Override
 protected Injector getInjector() {
    if(lifecycleInjector != null) return lifecycleInjector;
    this.lifecycleInjector = InjectorBuilder
            .fromModules(defineModules())
            .createInjector(Stage.DEVELOPMENT);
    return this.lifecycleInjector;
 }

 private List<Module> defineModules() {
    ArrayList<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new ServletModule());
    return modules;
 }
}
```

JerseyServletModule like:

```
public class ServletModule extends JerseyServletModule {
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(GuiceContainer.class).to(GovernatorServletContainer.class).asEagerSingleton();
    serve("/api/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
}
@Provides
ResourceConfig getResourceConfig() {
    final List<String> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.add("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
    final String[] arrayPackages = new String[resources.size()];
    resources.toArray(arrayPackages);
    return new RestApp(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put(PROPERTY_PACKAGES, arrayPackages)
            .put(FEATURE_DISABLE_WADL, "true")
            .build()); 
}
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {@Tag(name = "app API", description = "Administrative API for app")})
@ApplicationPath(RestApp.BASE_REST_APP_URI)
public class RestApp extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public static final String BASE_REST_APP_URI = "/api";
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(AppRestResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

How can I add the Swagger?

Comment: Please create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem so others can best assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks above all, I have fixed this problem. The sample is [sample of guice-jersey-swagger](https://github.com/melody792/guice-jersey-swagger-example)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with Guice but I can provide some pointers for the rest of your question.

In order to configure Swagger, you need to have your Jersey servlet configured like the following example. I'm using a web.xml, maybe someone can help you with a Guice configuration for this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>sample.app.ws.MyJavaWSApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,sample.app.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where `sample.app.ws` is the package containing your REST services. Then you need use the annotations from `io.swagger.annotations` to get Swagger to automatically generate your documentation. Here's one example of this:

```
package sample.app.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import sample.app.model.Book;

@Path("/books")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Api(value = "books")
public class BookService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a book", notes = "", response = Response.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful creation"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Resource could not be created")
    })
    public Response add(Book book) {
        // Implementation code
    }
}
```

In order to access the documentation, you can use Swagger UI to generate a nice page like [this](https://petstore.swagger.io/). I've tried doing this using `runtime 'org.webjars:swagger-ui:2.1.4'` but [couldn't get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261369/swagger-ui-configuration-via-jetty-xml), so I ended up downloading the folder and copying it to my webapp directory.

Comment: Hi, I copied the entirety of the **swaggerui** folder onto my project. Tries accessing it like this: http://localhost:8080/docs but unfortunately this does not work. Any idea on how to access the swagger UI? http://localhost:8080/swagger.json access is working fine though.